# Unable to download Media file in Android app sent from web app

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3

I am working on Chat Application, we have two Client one is Android and another is web,I am uploading Media files to **S3-Amazon**,when I am sending media file from Web App to android client Media file are not downloaded showing error as bellow.

`Media Download interrupted :                                                         com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: XXXXXXXXX), S3 Extended Request ID:XXXXXXXXXXX`

```
private void beginDownload(String key, String bucket, String 
 mediaType,final 
DownloadFileFromAwsCompletionListener listener) {
    // Location to download files from S3 to. You can choose any 
accessible
    // file.

    String localFilePath = Strings.EMPTY;
    try {
        //if (!isThumb) {
        localFilePath = MediaHelper.createMediaFile(mediaType, false, false, key);
       /* } else {
            localFilePath = MediaHelper.createMediaFile(mediaType, false, true);
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!StringHelper.isNullOrEmpty(localFilePath)) {
        File file = new File(localFilePath);

        // Initiate the download
        TransferObserver observer = mTransferUtility.download(bucket, key, file);
        final String finalLocalFilePath = localFilePath;
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {

                //String bucketPath = UrlStrings.XmppStrings.
                if (state.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED)) {
                    listener.onDownloadSuccess(finalLocalFilePath);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                listener.onDatabaseError(new AwsFailure(ex));
            }
        });
    } else {
        getLogger().log(Strings.TAG, "xmpp beginDownload(): file could not be created.");
    }
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint at `beginDownload`, `createMediaFile` and `catch ...` and start the debugger: what are the values for `key` and `localFilePath ` ?

Comment: Thanks it is working now,I missed one key in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cross check the uploaded path with which path you are using for downloading media files from S3. I think You are using the different path for downloading media files That's why you getting an error.